# Twitter Bootstrap carousel and navigation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the Twitter Bootstrap carousel on my website in full screen: [Web Site Link](http://dev.imjweb.fr/lelad)

In the bottom menu, click on "Architecture & Habitat" arrows appear to navigate through the slides.

My links are in this form: `<a id="projet-citizen" class="" data-interval="5000" data-slide-to="25" href="#myCarousel"> ... </ a>`

Access to each slide works well against the fade effect by stops often, especially if I want to go to a previous slide. Have you ever had this problem? Did I miss something?

Comment: Please provide your relevant css3 transition, I think you miss .carousel .prev {left: 0; opacity: 1; z-index: 1;}

Comment: Thank you very much, I do not think the problem was CSS :)
I put it: carousel active.right.. {Left: 0, opacity: 0, z-index: 2;} and my problem was solved.
I also found this post that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526970/can-the-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-plugin-fade-in-and-out-on-slide-transition

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap Carousel have no built-in javascript/jQuery effects for transitions; they are done using CSS transitions.

To handle the back transition you have to set in your CSS:

```
.carousel .active.right {Left: 0, opacity: 0, z-index: 2;}
```

Other relevant question: [Can the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel plugin fade in and out on slide transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526970/can-the-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-plugin-fade-in-and-out-on-slide-transition)