# How can I change the sliding animation to fade in/out with transition on Bootstrap3 Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to change the sliding effect of bootstrap 3 carousel to fade in/out. I followed the instruction given here [Can the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel plugin fade in and out on slide transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526970/can-the-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-plugin-fade-in-and-out-on-slide-transition)

the css code is (said in the link) below

```
.carousel .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -o-transition: opacity 3s; 
    transition: opacity 3s;
}
.carousel .active.left {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.carousel .next {
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
}
```

My example link is at the end of of this pagragraph, I am making it but problem is the previous button isn't working perfectly, may be the solution is perfect for bootstrap2, I am using bootstrap3, can anybody help me? Advance Thanks for your help. I am new here, very sorry for my poor English and if I asked a stupid question!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35758776/xenxbd/contrastic/index.html#parallux-wrapper-04

Comment: Looks like you need to modify opacity of .prev class too. Example: http://bootply.com/86170

Comment: Thank you friend, I got it now. But I can't give you thumb up, don't know why!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this carousel fade example. It will show you how to change opacity for prev and next buttons.

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

http://bootply.com/86170

Answer (score 1):

Add class ".carousel-fade" in your carousel.
css:

```
.carousel-fade .active.left {
        left:0;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /*time < to $.carousel.interval setup */
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s; 
        -ms-transition: opacity1s; 
        -o-transition: opacity 1s; 
        transition: opacity  1s;
        z-index:2;

}

.carousel-fade .next {

    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;

}
```