# Bootstrap carousel slide with fading+sliding

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been struggling a few days on bootstrap carousel, that should slide left/right like the default one, but with added fading (new item slowly gain opacity when coming in and previous item slowly loses opacity when moving out), I've tried many variations, but some of them doesn't work in Firefox, other keeps failing in opera etc.

Here is the HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Some title</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <div class="ingo col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div id="pubCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img class="foto" src="{{'assets/img/some-image.jpg'|theme }}"/>
                                <h3 class="name longn">Carousel text</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="foto" src="{{'assets/img/some-image.jpg'|theme }}"/>
                                <h3 class="name">Carousel text</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="pub-counter">
                            <p class="counter-line"></p>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#pubCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#pubCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my carousel setup which doesn't work (I know it's bad right now, I tried like 10 solutions but it doesn't work anyway), rest of the carousel is default:

```
.ingo .carousel-inner>.item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
.ingo .carousel-inner>.item.active,.ingo .carousel-inner>.item.active {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
.ingo .carousel .item {
    opacity:0;
}
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .next,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .prev
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .active.left,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .next.left,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I'm not using any JS modification. I hope this answer doesn't duplicate some already posted question, I just couldn't find the solution.

Thanks for all the help guys, appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial on sitepoint should help you out: http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations/

Animate.css is very good CSS3 library which I have used on many projects to "spice things up".

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of struggling I finally managed to get slide+fade effect, I also found this Stackoverflow topic [Can the Twitter Bootstrap Carousel plugin fade in and out on slide transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526970/can-the-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-plugin-fade-in-and-out-on-slide-transition?rq=1), but any posted solution didn't work for every browser - especially Firefox did a lot of trouble. So there is a solution. Hope this helps someone.

```
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1.1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 1.1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1.1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1.1s ease-in-out, opacity 1s ease-in;
}
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .item,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .active.left,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .active.right {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .active,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .next.left,
.ingo .carousel .carousel-inner .prev.right {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.#pubCarousel.carousel .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and check the example code [HERE](https://codepen.io/abianjali00/pen/ayWrPZ)

```css
.carousel-caption{
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #f65a3a;
 font-weight:400 !important;
 -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
 animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
 animation-delay: 3s; 
 color: #0d9b56;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
 -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
 animation-delay: 6s; 
 color: #f65a3a; 
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s; 
 -ms-animation-delay: 9s; 
 animation-delay: 9s; 
 color:#0d9b56;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
 5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
 20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-30px); }
 5% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
 20% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(30px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); transform: translateY(-30px); }
 5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px); }
 20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); transform: translateY(30px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.rw-words{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 10px;
}
.agileits-banner-info span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.agileits_w3layouts_more a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background:#0d9b56;
    padding: .7em 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
 border-radius:2px;
}
.agileits_w3layouts_more a:focus{
 outline:none;
}
.agileits_w3layouts_more a:hover{
 background:#f65a3a;
}
.agileits_w3layouts_more.menu__item {
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

/*
WHAT IS NEW IN 3.3: "Added transforms to improve carousel performance in modern browsers."
now override the 3.3 new styles for modern browsers & apply opacity
*/
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4500">
    
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
       
        <img src="http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/284/images/pic1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
           <div class="agileits-banner-info bannertext-desktop">
     <span>A Powerful But Simple Way to Manage Your  </span>
     <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
      <span>Company</span>
      <span> People</span>
      <span>Happiness</span>
      <span>Wonder</span>
     </div>
     <div class="agileits_w3layouts_more menu__item">
      <a href="#" class="menu__link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Learn More</a>
     </div>
          </div> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/284/images/pic2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <div class="agileits-banner-info bannertext-desktop">
     <span>A Powerful But Simple Way to Manage Your  </span>
     <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
      <span>Company</span>
      <span> People</span>
      <span>Happiness</span>
      <span>Wonder</span>
     </div>
     <div class="agileits_w3layouts_more menu__item">
      <a href="#" class="menu__link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Learn More</a>
     </div>
          </div> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/284/images/pic3.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
           <div class="agileits-banner-info bannertext-desktop">
     <span>A Powerful But Simple Way to Manage Your  </span>
     <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
      <span>Company</span>
      <span> People</span>
      <span>Happiness</span>
      <span>Wonder</span>
     </div>
     <div class="agileits_w3layouts_more menu__item">
      <a href="#" class="menu__link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Learn More</a>
     </div>
          </div> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
  
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```